# Swipe left & right works all the time, but swipe up/down doesn't

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I have an object based on UIView that I've set up to recognise swipe gestures. The view has another UIView based object in the middle of it.

When I swipe left or right, regardless of where I put my finger, the correct event fires.

When I swipe up or down the correct event only fires if my finger isn't starting in the subview in the middle?

Why?

Here's the init code for the object:

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [self setFrame:CGRectMake(0,
                                  0,
                                  [self getScreenWidth],
                                  [self getScreenHeight])];
        backView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,
                                                            0,
                                                            [self getScreenWidth],
                                                            [self getScreenHeight])];
        backView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        [self addSubview:backView];
        [self bringSubviewToFront:backView];

        theCard = [[actCard alloc] init:CARD_POS_CENTER];
        [backView addSubview:theCard];
        [backView bringSubviewToFront:theCard];

        swipeLeft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                              action:@selector(showGestureForSwipeRecognizer:)];
        swipeRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                               action:@selector(showGestureForSwipeRecognizer:)];
        swipeUp = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                            action:@selector(showGestureForSwipeRecognizer:)];
        swipeDown = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                              action:@selector(showGestureForSwipeRecognizer:)];
        [swipeLeft setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft];
        [self addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeft];
        [swipeRight setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight];
        [self addGestureRecognizer:swipeRight];
        [swipeUp setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp];
        [self addGestureRecognizer:swipeUp];
        [swipeDown setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown];
        [self addGestureRecognizer:swipeDown];
        NSLog(@"Enabled: %d",swipeLeft.isEnabled);
        NSLog(@"Enabled: %d",swipeRight.isEnabled);
        NSLog(@"Enabled: %d",swipeUp.isEnabled);
        NSLog(@"Enabled: %d",swipeDown.isEnabled);

    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obvious! What a newb I am.
The UITextView still had scrollEnabled. That means the UITextView took the up & down swipes, they don't get passed on to the view.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the delegate of your Upward swipe and downward swipe to be your MainViewController.Something like :

```
swipeDown .delegate  =   self;
swipeUp .delegate = self;
```

This should make your main view controller ( which contains the secondary UIView ) responsible for the gestures received.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, but tried that and it makes no difference. I also thought it might be because I've set my app to only use landscape, so I enabled it in portrait & that made no difference either.

Comment: Noticed something else. The actCard object is a UIView with a UITextView in the middle of it. The up and down events fire if I start the swipe outside the UITextView ... still doesn't make sense, cos the left/right events fire regardless of where I touch.

Comment: Okay, try this. Add the gesture recognizers to actCard as well but set the delegate to be the Main View Controller. What we will be asking then is that the main view controller will be responsible for the gestures which originate in the actCard as well ( when the touch event starts in the actCard). I am sure that the event is not being passed to the superview that needs to be circumvented. Plz let me know what you find out.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion Abhishek, but got exactly the same behaviour. It's puzzling that left and right swipes work as expected, whilst the up and down swipes only work when the swipe starts in the owner view, given that all four gesture recognizers seem to be coded the same .....

Comment: If you can upload your project somewhere, I can try to look at it. It is really weird behavior, you are correct in saying that.

Comment: It was just me being dumb Abhishek! There was a scrollable UITextView in the middle of actCard object. The scrolling of the text view took precedence over the swipe gestures.

Comment: We all find ourselves in that situation now and then Ian. Glad that you finally found out the reason.